# How can I save a vector entered by a user using a subprogram?

Tags: c, vector, scanf

Just started learning C, and it would be great if you could help me with the following:

I just wrote a program that saves a 4-component vector entered by the user (using function called `save_vector`), and prints it (using function called `print_vector`).

However, I am not sure how to make the function `save_vector` work. The other function `print_vector` seems to be working just fine.

Looking forward to reading any suggestions to improve this piece of code! Thank you! :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_vector(int,float *);
void save_vector(n,v+i);


int main(void)
{

    const int n=4;
    int i;
    float v[4];

    puts("Enter the 4 components of the vector:");
    save_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe vector is:");
    print_vector(n, v);

    return 0;
}

void save_vector(int N, float v+i)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%f",v+i);
}

void print_vector(int N, float V[N])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf(" %.2f ",*(V+i));
}
```

Comment: `v+i` is not a valid variable name in C. If that supposed to be `v[N]` in the function declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the declare to

```
void save_vector(int ,float *);
```

or with the name of the arguments, if you want.

```
void save_vector(int N, float * v)
```

Because, `n` and `v+i` are not declared, so you can not use them in the declaration of `save_vector` function.

And in the implementation of `save_vector`:

```
void save_vector(int N, float * v)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        scanf("%f",v+i);
}
```

Comment: This worked just perfect! @Hitokiri. Thank you very much for this! Just one thing I still struggle to understand: why the `save_vector` function uses `float * V` but the `print_vector` one uses `float V[N]`? I think I understand how to work with pointers, but I am still missing something to understand this part better. It would be great if you could shed some light here! Thank you! :-)

Comment: you can use `void print_vector(int N, float *V])` also. The diffrence is if you use `float *V` the size of pointer can reallocate in this function, if you want, float V[N] is an array so, its size cannot change.